# GetMetaData()->the state of the cursor is not correct

Tags: java, position, cursor, ucanaccess

I have been trying to use Ucanacces with getMetaData() but im getting some problems, this error when I try to show the information:

> Error de SQLException:net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 estado del cursor incorrecto: cursor indicado no está posicionado en una fila para sentencia UPDATE, DELETE, SET, o GET: ; Posición actual del resultado de la consulta es antes del primer registro

In English it means that

> UCAExc:::4.0.1 the state of the cursor is not correct: cursor
>   indicated is not positioned in a row UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or GET
>   statement.:; Current position of the result of the query is before the
>   first registration

(sorry for translating myself).

So i think that probably the mistake is when trying to access the data when im trying to print it:

```
        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        String sql= "SELECT * FROM BARCO";
        ResultSet result=statement.executeQuery(sql);
        ResultSetMetaData rmeta=result.getMetaData();
        int numColums=rmeta.getColumnCount();
        for(int i=1;i<=numColums;++i){
            if (i>numColums){
                System.out.print(result.getString(rmeta.getColumnName(i))+"|");;
            }else {
                System.out.println(result.getString(rmeta.getColumnName(i)));
            }
        }
        while(result.next()){
            for(int i=1;i<=numColums;++i){
                if(i<numColums){
                    System.out.print(result.getString(rmeta.getColumnName(i))+"|");
                }else{
                    System.out.println(result.getString(rmeta.getColumnName(i)));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this part of the code:

```
for(int i=1;i<=numColums;++i){
        if (i>numColums){
            System.out.print(result.getString(rmeta.getColumnName(i))+"|");;
        }else {
            System.out.println(result.getString(rmeta.getColumnName(i)));
        }
    }
```

You are trying to read from the `ResultSet` when the cursor is not moved to an actual row, its initial position is `-1`. You can iterate through a `ResultSet` by calling the `next()` method (as you have done in your second **for loop**). The method `next()` moves the cursor forward by one row (if there are rows) and returns `true`. When it reaches the end of the `ResultSet` it returns `false`. You can position the cursor by using other methods (i.e. `relative(int rows)` etc.) For more detail see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

If you want to print the column names on the first row, then replace the above code with:

```
for(int i=1;i<=numColums;i++){
   System.out.print(rmeta.getColumnName(i)+"\t");
}
System.out.println();
```